# AES Encrypting for ESP8266 implemented on Software or Hardware? How to implement?

Tags: encryption, aes, esp8266, nodemcu

I need to write a basic encryption program for ESP8266. I did read the datasheet (https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/0a-esp8266ex_datasheet_en.pdf), and them says that existis the methods of encrypt: WEP/TKIP/AES. My main question is: The AES method, is implemented on software or hardware? This module is very simple, (36KB RAM, 90MHz CPU clock), so the algorithm is heavy to process. If AES is implemented in hardware, I think this task gets simpler, but I don't know how to use this. I did read at web, and the examples uses a `#include "AES.h"` lib, I don't know if this is implemented on hardware or software. The site of ESP8266 don't reply this question. So, I wants know about this and how, or where I found help, to implement this.

Ps.: I don't want use Arduino.

Also, I've already use this, https://github.com/CHERTS/esp8266-devkit/tree/master/Espressif/examples/ESP8266. But, for little jobs.

Comment: let me know if you find something, i had to use a stream cipher for large SPIFFS files and would like something more "legit"

Answer (score 1):

It's a software implementation. The RTOS SDK contains two implementations of AES, one of them shared with the basic SDK - all in software:

- https://github.com/CHERTS/esp8266-devkit/blob/master/Espressif/ESP8266_RTOS_SDK/third_party/mbedtls/library/aes.c
- https://github.com/CHERTS/esp8266-devkit/blob/master/Espressif/ESP8266_RTOS_SDK/third_party/ssl/crypto/ssl_aes.c
- https://github.com/CHERTS/esp8266-devkit/blob/master/Espressif/ESP8266_SDK/third_party/mbedtls/library/aes.c

In addition, there's an implementation optimized for the AES-NI instruction set: https://github.com/CHERTS/esp8266-devkit/blob/master/Espressif/ESP8266_RTOS_SDK/third_party/mbedtls/library/aesni.c

However, AES-NI is only implemented by certain Intel and AMD CPUs. So it will not be compiled.

There are no signs of a hardware implementation.

Comment: Oh yes, I've looked this links. But in the official Espressif Github, I found `aesni` implementation, unfortunattely by third party. But, reading the codes, I found the instruction set assembly: https://github.com/espressif/ESP8266_NONOS_SDK/blob/master/third_party/mbedtls/library/aesni.c. I'm not sure, but I think is hardware implementation. And in the wikipedia, I found the AES-NI: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set. These instruction, are being used in the code of `aesni.c`. So, I think that this is my solution, this is hardware implementation!. But, I'm not sure.

Comment: Also, I don't know how this is here, maybe someone implemented it for the ESP8266 architecture.

Comment: AES-NI instructions are not available in the Xtensa processor. They are specific to certain x86_64 CPUs from Intel and AMD. The code is skipped and not compiled (also see `#if defined(MBEDTLS_HAVE_X86_64`, which skips almost the entire file). ESP8266 most likely uses a pure software solution using standard instructions.

Comment: Why it’s included on ESP8266 repository, if not compile ?

Comment: It's part of the [mbed TLS library](https://tls.mbed.org/), which is not specific to ESP8266 but used on many systems. For hardware acceleration see the bigger brother ESP32: https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/master/components/esp32/hwcrypto/aes.c (specifically the function `esp_aes_block`).

Comment: I can't see assembly code in this code, how It implementing hardware optimization? I've readed `DPORT_REG_WRITE` but not found the declaration. So, in ESP32 I can use the hardware support for accelerate AES cryption?

Comment: Unlike AES NI, it's not implemented as additional assembler instructions. Instead, there's dedicated hardware module within the microprocessor that is accessed and controlled by writing to and reading from fixed addresses (AES_TEXT_BASE, AES_START_REG and AES_IDLE_REG in this case). The absolute addresses are declared in https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/master/components/soc/esp32/include/soc/hwcrypto_reg.h. The AES accelerator is documented in the [ESP32 technical reference manual](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32_technical_reference_manual_en.pdf).